# Homebrew httpd suddenly stopped working in Ventura. "Successfully started" but status says "stopped."

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon, apache

My Homebrew Apache installation randomly stopped working today. It was working up until yesterday, and I was able to access my projects via `localhost:8080`.

I recently updated my OS from Monterey to Ventura 13.6.3 about two days ago. I am on Apple Silicon (MacBook Air M1 2020).

I have tried restarting httpd using `brew services restart httpd` or stopping and starting using `brew services stop httpd` and `brew services start httpd`.

I observed that the service would "successfully start" for roughly a second before the status becomes `stopped` in `brew services list`

```
ron@Rons-MacBook-Air ~ % brew services start httpd
==> Successfully started `httpd` (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)
ron@Rons-MacBook-Air ~ % brew services list       
Name              Status  User       File
httpd             started ronnparcia ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
mongodb-community started ronnparcia ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
mysql             started ronnparcia ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
php               started ronnparcia ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
unbound           none               
ron@Rons-MacBook-Air ~ % brew services list
Name              Status  User       File
httpd             stopped ronnparcia ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
mongodb-community started ronnparcia ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
mysql             started ronnparcia ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
php               started ronnparcia ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
unbound           none
```

I have tried solutions online such as reinstalling httpd and restoring the default `httpd.conf` file but this did not work. I have also updated and upgraded Homebrew already.

I have also tried the `launchctl unload -w` command but this returns a Input/Output error.

May I please ask for help in troubleshooting and resolving this issue? Please let me know if there's any additional information or output I can provide.

Comment: What do the log files say? If there isn't anything useful there, you may need to increase the [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel) and restart `httpd`.

Comment: @nohillside I've increased the LogLevel to `trace8` and restarted the service. I tried  `tail -f /opt/homebrew/var/log/httpd/error_log` but there doesn't seem to be any new log entries.

Comment: Have there been any log entries since you migrated to Ventura? If not, I would put "access rights" on top of the list of things to look into.

Comment: @nohillside There weren't any different entries since the migration. There's been a AH00558 warning but that has always been there repeatedly since I installed httpd in August. I did notice, however, that the logs stopped today at 11 am.